# How to pass a parameter to apoc.export.csv.query in python?

Tags: python, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to send data from a CSV file to apoc query in python.
My query looks like follows:

```
"""

            CALL apoc.export.csv.query("MATCH(n:Entity{EntityType:'Configuration_Item', Name:$CI_name}) --(ev:Event)--(c:Common)
            optional match (c)--(ev_c:Event)--(en:Entity)
            where en.EntityType='Change' or en.EntityType='Interaction'
            with  en.EntityType as ent,ev_c.Activity as act, en.IDraw as ID, ev.Start as date
            order by ev.Start where not ent='null'
            return collect(act), ID, ent", "results.csv",{stream:true, params:{CI_Name:$CI_name}})
           """
```

and the Python code which sends the data is as follows:

```
with open ('CI.csv','r') as first_file:
csv_f = csv.DictReader(first_file)
for row in csv_f:
    counter(row["n.Name"])
```

However, I am getting the following error

raise CypherError.hydrate(*metadata)
neobolt.exceptions.ClientError: Expected parameter(s): CI_name

Could you help me with fixing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the query as follows:

```
 query="""  

            CALL apoc.export.csv.query("MATCH(n:Entity{EntityType:'Configuration_Item'}) --(ev:Event)--(c:Common)
            where n.Name='%s'
            optional match (c)--(ev_c:Event)--(en:Entity)
            where en.EntityType='Change' or en.EntityType='Interaction'
            with  en.EntityType as ent,ev_c.Activity as act, en.IDraw as ID, ev.Start as date
            order by ev.Start where not ent='null'
            return collect(act), ID, ent", "/results_test.csv",{stream:true})
            """
query = query % (CI_name)
graph.run(query)
```

source: https://pythonpedia.com/en/tutorial/5841/neo4j-and-cypher-using-py2neo